# Jquery date picker error for islamic calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am getting javascript runtime error: Unable to get property 'regional' of undefined or null reference.

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.calendars.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.calendars.plus.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.calendars.picker.lang.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.calendars.picker.lang.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.calendars.picker-ar.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () 

     {

      $('#TextBox1').calendars.picker($.extend( { calendar: $.calendars.instance('arabic', 'ar-EG') }, $.calendars.picker.regional['ar-EG'] ));

     });
</script>
```

Comment: You are declaring the `Scripts/jquery.calendars.picker.lang.js` script twice. Maybe this is causing the issue.

Comment: I have deleted that line but still, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Which calendar plugin is it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download `jquery` lib for islamic calendar .

```
jquery.calendars.islamic.min.js
```

then use it like this:

```
 $('#TextBox1').calendarsPicker({ calendar: $.calendars.instance('islamic') });
```